# Replacing (12345) with negative

Tags: ruby

I am trying to replace some strings with parenthesis to be negative numbers:

e.g. "(12345)" would become "-12345"
"(1,23)" would become "-1,23"
"(1.55)" would become "-1.55"

This is what I have tried:

```
amount = value[sum.to_sym].gsub /\((.+)\)/ , "-#$1"
```

but it returns "-" in some instances e.g. "(59,006)"

Is there a better way to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is your substitution pattern, not your regular expression. The string interpolation `"-#$1"` (short for `"-#{$1}"`) is evaluated before the call to `gsub`, so your replacement pattern is whatever $1 was at the time of the call to `gsub`.

You can either fix this by doing

```
gsub /\((.+)\)/ , "-\\1"
```

where \1 denotes the first capture group or using the block form

```
gsub(/\((.+)\)/) { "-#$1" }
```

If performance were critical the second is probably slower since gsub has to call the block but it is unlikely to make a difference

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is fine. Use brackets or `\1`

```
"(59,006.23)".gsub(/\((.+)\)/){"-#$1"} #=> "-59,006.23"
"(59,006.23)".gsub(/\((.+)\)/,'-\1')   #=> "-59,006.23"
```

The problem with your current code is it's giving `"-#$1"` as an argument to `gsub`. At that point, $1 has not been updated yet, and hence holds the value of your last match. (Try doing some regex matching before the `gsub` and you'll see what I'm talking about)